# Como calcular o número da semana do ano em Javascript puro, sem depender de bibliotecas?

Tags: javascript

Abaixo, apresento minha tentativa, a qual se apresenta inconsistente:

```
function getYearlyWeekNumber(myDate)
{
    var this_date = new Date(myDate.getFullYear(),myDate.getMonth(),myDate.getDate(),0,0,0);
    var y_first_day = new Date(myDate.getFullYear(),0,1,0,0,0);
    var y_first_sun = new Date(myDate.getFullYear(),0,1+y_first_day.getDay(),0,0,0);
    var y_last_sat_before = new Date(myDate.getFullYear(),myDate.getMonth(),myDate.getDate()-myDate.getDay()+1,0,0,0);
    var y_sundaycount = dateDiff('ww', y_first_sun, y_last_sat_before);
    return y_sundaycount + ((y_first_day.getDay()<3) ? 1 : 2);
}
```

**EDIT 20/04/2019**: Refazendo os cálculos (grato pelas considerações). O código abaixo considera Domingo como o primeiro da semana, e usa a ISO 8601 para definir quando se inicia a primeira semana. Ainda está incompleto, conforme consta nos comentários.

```
function getYearlyWeekNumber(myDate)
{
    var today = new Date(myDate.getFullYear(),myDate.getMonth(),myDate.getDate(),0,0,0);
    var first_of_month = new Date(myDate.getFullYear(),myDate.getMonth(),1,0,0,0);
    var first_of_year = new Date(myDate.getFullYear(),0,1,0,0,0);
    var q_dias = dateDiff('d', first_of_year, today);
    var numero_semana = Math.floor(q_dias / 7);
    // ajuste de contagem   
    if (today.getDay()<first_of_year.getDay()) ++numero_semana;
    // ISO 8601
    if (first_of_year.getDay()<=3) ++numero_semana;
    // Datas antes do primeiro Domingo resultarão em zero, 
    // o que significa que pertencem à última semana do ano anterior.
    // Ainda me falta fazer isso. 
    return numero_semana;
}
```

Comment: Eu também quis um dia ter essa funcionalidade sem usar uma biblioteca... e acabei escrevendo [uma biblioteca](https://github.com/SergioCrisostomo/js-calendar) para fazer isso :) Repara que o número da semana calcula-se de maneira diferente nos EUA e na Europa. Não é propriamente trivial...

Comment: Isso depende da definição que vc vai usar (qual o primeiro dia da semana, e o mínimo de dias da primeira semana). A norma [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date), por exemplo, define o primeiro dia = Segunda e no mínimo 4 dias na primeira semana - ou seja, a primeira semana de 2019 é o período de 7 dias que começa em uma segunda-feira e tem no mínimo 4 dias em 2019 (que é 31/12/18 a 06/01/2019).  Ha países em que o primeiro dia é domingo e o mínimo de dias na primeira semana é 1, então a primeira semana é de 30/12/18 a 05/01/19. E há lugares em que a semana começa no sábado...

Comment: Resumindo, não é algo tão trivial, e como o @Sergio disse, talvez seja melhor usar uma lib mesmo. O [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/week/), por exemplo, possui essa funcionalidade.

Comment: @hkotsubo Bem lembrado. Pretendo usar o Domingo como o primeiro da semana (ou "cabeça da semana") e adotar a citada norma ISO 8601 (mínimo de 4 dias na primeira semana do ano).

Comment: Mesmo assim ainda acho mais simples usar uma lib, como o Moment.js, que possui uma [função pronta pra isso](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/iso-week/). Não sei se vale a pena fazer manualmente algo tão difícil e propenso a erros quando já existe algo confiável - tem gente que adiciona dependências [pra coisas bem mais simples e desnecessárias](https://www.davidhaney.io/npm-left-pad-have-we-forgotten-how-to-program/), por que não adicionar uma para coisas complexas? :-) Bom, mas se mesmo assim não quiser usar a lib,  vc pode se basear no [código deles](https://github.com/moment/moment/)

Comment: @hkotsubo Boa! Vou dar uma olhada. Também quero portar essa funcionalidade para usar num site em ASP Classic (VBScript) e possivelmente VBA. Muito obrigado !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Veja se esta função te ajuda

```
function semana(ano,mes,dia) {
function serie(dias) { return 86400000*dias; }
function dateserial(ano,mes,dia) { return (new Date(ano,mes-1,dia).valueOf()); }
function weekdia(date) { return (new Date(date)).getdia()+1; }
function anoserial(date) { return (new Date(date)).getFullano(); }
var date = ano instanceof Date ? ano.valueOf() : typeof ano === "string" ? new Date(ano).valueOf() : dateserial(ano,mes,dia), 
    date2 = dateserial(anoserial(date - serial(weekdia(date-serial(1))) + serial(4)),1,3);
return ~~((date - date2 + serial(weekdia(date2) + 5))/ serial(7));
```

}

Comment: Sugeri umas correções e botei para rodar no console do Chrome, colei o resultado no pastebin https://pastebin.com/sr0ekGf9. Acredito ser um bom caminho, sobretudo para quem precisa de começar a semana na segunda-feira, o que pode ser adaptado com algum esforço. Obrigado.

Answer (score -2):

function

```js
function getYearlyWeekNumber( date ){
  let splitedDate = date.split("-")
  let dateObj = new Date(+splitedDate[0], +splitedDate[1]-1, +splitedDate[2], 0,0,0,0 )
  let firstDayYear = new Date(+splitedDate[0],0,1,0,0,0,0 )
  let yearDay = ((dateObj - firstDayYear) / 86400000)+1
  let weekInYear = +(String((yearDay + firstDayYear.getDay()+1) / 7).split(".")[0])
  return { date, yearDay, weekInYear }
 }
 
console.log( getYearlyWeekNumber("2020-01-01") )
console.log( getYearlyWeekNumber("2020-01-15") ) 
console.log( getYearlyWeekNumber("2020-01-20") ) 

console.log( getYearlyWeekNumber("2020-02-29") ) 
console.log( getYearlyWeekNumber("2020-04-10") ) 
console.log( getYearlyWeekNumber("2020-11-09") )
console.log( getYearlyWeekNumber("2020-12-31") )
```

```
getYearlyWeekNumber( date ){
                let splitedDate = date.split("-")
                let dateObj = new Date(+splitedDate[0], +splitedDate[1]-1, +splitedDate[2], 0,0,0,0 )
                let firstDayYear = new Date(+splitedDate[0],0,1,0,0,0,0 )
                let yearDay = ((dateObj - firstDayYear) / 86400000)+1
                let weekInYear = +(String((yearDay + firstDayYear.getDay()+1) / 7).split(".")[0])
                return { date, yearDay, weekInYear }
            }
```

Comment: O Stack Overflow é sobre [ensinar a pescar e não sobre dar o peixe](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1968/ensinar-a-pescar-ou-dar-o-peixe).

Answer (score -3):

agora sim

```js
getYearlyWeekNumber( date ){
  let splitedDate = date.split("-")
  let dateObj = new Date(+splitedDate[0], +splitedDate[1]-1, +splitedDate[2], 0,0,0,0 )
  let firstDayYear = new Date(+splitedDate[0],0,1,0,0,0,0 )
  let yearDay = ((dateObj - firstDayYear) / 86400000)
  let weekInYear = +(String((yearDay + firstDayYear.getDay()) / 7).split(".")[0])
  return { date, yearDay, weekInYear }
}
```

Comment: Que negócio é esse??? [O Stack Overflow não é um forum](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2068/o-stack-overflow-em-portugu%c3%aas-%c3%a9-um-f%c3%b3rum). Nós somos um site de perguntas e respostas, não é apenas jogar um código e a pessoa que se vire. Você deve ensinar o conceito, a solução codificada deve ser apenas um complemento de prova que o conceito ensinado é correto